# How should we understand the use (G3588) in Eph.1:10?

Tags: greek, grammar

When it says in Eph.1:10: unto a dispensation *of the* fulness *of the* seasons, to...

Can it be understood as: unto a dispensation of the fullness, *the* seasons to ...

Having the meaning of the dispensation of the fullness *are the* seasons to...

Or can it be a dispensation of the fullness *for* *the* seasons to...

Or can it be a dispensation *for the* fullness of the seasons to..(later added)

Can anyone help with if the Greek can give us the meaning of the use of (G3588)?

Comment: _in regard to the dispensation of the fulness of the times,_ [Young's Literal Translation]. There is no doubt at all that this is a genitive expression . . . . .  'of'. See also The Englishman's Greek New Testament literal interlinear.

Comment: What about "unto a dispensation for the fullness of the seasons" do you think that is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

In Ephesians 1:10, both "πληρώματος" (G4138), translated as "fulness", and "καιρῶν" (G2540), translated as "times" (per KJV), are in the Greek *genitive* case.  This means that the "of" is implied, and even though the Greek does not have a separate word for "of" explicitly in the text, the English translation requires it.

The G3588 is simply the definite article in Greek, i.e. "the."  By itself, it implies no specific preposition, but it does change form to follow the case of the noun it modifies--in this case the genitive.  It is the genitive case that invokes the "of" in the English translation.

Greek may use a list of prepositions in conjunction with a genitive.  These, along with a cute cartoon illustration, can be seen [HERE.](https://www.publiconsulting.com/wordpress/ancientgreek/chapter/16-prepositions/)  Because the genitive itself denotes a belonging relationship, the "of" is inherent.

For example, if I say "my car" (possessive) without the "my", I might say "car *of* mine/me."  The "of" is what connects the item to its possessor.  If I say "season of rain" it would be the same as the (ungrammatical/unidiomatic) "rain's season." Greek doesn't need the "of" because "rain" would be in the genitive case to indicate this relationship; but English needs the "of" to connect them.  Now, could one say "season *for* rain" instead?  Possibly.  Could we say "season, rain"? No.  Could we say "season *is/are* rain"? Again, no.

The same holds true for the example translations in the question.  The last sentence, which has "a dispensation of the fullness *for* the seasons to...," is a marginal possibility, but the "of" is typically better.  The other sentences would not be correct translations.

Comment: Are you saying the dispensation, and the fulness of the seasons are one in the same or is a dispensation for or concerning the fullness of the seasons. are they one and the same or, is one concerning the other in your knowledge of the Greek?

Comment: I often find Paul's writings to be worded in a way that likely meets other minds than mine. To me they often seem esoteric and verbose. But carefully examining this verse leads me to conclude that Paul is speaking of an organizational system (dispensation), a "Gospel order" if you will, that's fully up to the times and brings all things together in Christ, both in heaven and on earth. In other words, Paul appears to be contemplating the _comprehensiveness_ of the post-atonement-era government/order in Christ's church. To see the big picture, one must retrace a few verses; it's a long sentence.

Comment: it seems the problem is with the word fullness, it stuck in the middle. Could it be that the meaning of fullness goes in both directions, like the dispensing of the fullness, is of the fullness of the seasons to gather all in Christ. Kind of like a double use of the meaning of fullness? like fullness being dispensed for or to bring in the remaining seasons, or their full arrival?

Comment: I might point out that "fulness" in the Bible, with reference to time, is used almost in the sense of "due."  Consider these verses: 
"Now Elisabeth's **full time** came that she should be delivered; and she brought forth a son." (Luke 1:57) "Go ye up unto this feast: I go not up yet unto this feast: for my time is not yet **full come.**" (John 7:8) "But when **the fulness of the time** was come, God sent forth his Son, made of a woman, made under the law," (Galatians 4:4).  So perhaps "in the dispensation of the _due_ time" is even a possibility...still left open to interpretation, though.

Comment: The due times to head up all are the appointed seasons. is seasons used singular or plural in this verse do you know?

Comment: The word "καιρῶν" (times) in Greek is plural.  However, its idiomatic sense may still be singular.  I'm not as proficient in Greek as in Hebrew, having taken fewer Greek courses, so I am unsure of its specific application here.  However, in Hebrew, some words are always plural, such as "heavens/skies", "waters", "faces", etc.  It is context that tells us if they should be translated as plural or singular.  In English if we say "skies" we still know there is only one sky.  If we speak of "modern times," we are speaking of only the present time, singular.  Why the plural? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's translation of the Eph 1:10 is slightly misleading./  Here is a very literal translation of the verse:

> for administration **of the** fullness **of the** times, to bring
> together all **the** things in **the** Christ-- **the** [things] in **the** heavens and **the**
> [things] upon **the** earth

Notice that "G3588", highlighted above, is simply the definite article, "the".

Next, the word, οἰκονομία (oikonomia) simply means:

> management of household affairs, stewardship, administration

Thus, "dispensation" is a rather misleading translation and unique to the KJV and NKJV.

Eph 1:10 cannot be divorced from its surrounding verses - it is a single sentence in the Greek extending from V3 to V14.  So, let me quote the entire sentence:

> **3** Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places in
> Christ, **4** just as He chose us in Him before the foundation of the
> world, that we would be holy and blameless before Him. In love **5**
> He predestined us to adoption as sons and daughters through Jesus
> Christ to Himself, according to the good pleasure of His will, **6**
> to the praise of the glory of His grace, with which He favored us in
> the Beloved **7** Whom we have redemption through His blood, the
> forgiveness of our wrongdoings, according to the riches of His grace
> **8** which He lavished on us. In all wisdom and insight **9** making known to us the mystery of His will, according to His good pleasure
> which He set forth in Him, **10** regarding His plan of the fullness
> of the times, to bring all things together in Christ, things in the
> heavens and things on the earth; **11** in Whom we also have obtained
> an inheritance, having been predestined according to the purpose of
> Him who works all things in accordance with the plan of His will,
> **12** to the end that we who were the first to hope in the Christ would be to the praise of His glory; **13** Whom, you also, after
> listening to the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation—having
> also believed, you were sealed in Whom with the Holy Spirit of the
> promise, **14** who is a first installment of our inheritance, in
> regard to the redemption of God’s own possession, to the praise of His
> glory.

This is quintessential Paul with his long sentences.  So what is Paul saying here?  Let me set this out in point form to make it clearer:

Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ,

- God has blessed us with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places in Christ,
- God chose chose us in Christ before the foundation of the world,
- we are to be holy and blameless before God.
- In love He intended us to adoption as sons and daughters through Jesus Christ to Himself, according to the good pleasure of His will, to the praise of the glory of His grace, with which He favored us in the Beloved.
- In Christ we have redemption through His blood, the forgiveness of our wrongdoings, according to the riches of His grace
- Christ lavished grace on us.
- In all wisdom and insight God made known to us the mystery of His will, according to His good pleasure which He set forth in Christ,
- V10: **regarding God's plan/management of the fullness of the times, to bring all things together in Christ, things in the heavens and things on the earth.**
- In Christ we also have obtained an inheritance, having been predestined according to the purpose of Him who works all things in accordance with the plan of His will,
- to the end that we who were the first to hope in the Christ would be to the praise of His glory.
- In Christ, you also, after listening to the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation—having also believed, you were sealed in Christ with the Holy Spirit of the promise, who is a first installment of our inheritance, in regard to the redemption of God’s own possession, to the praise of His glory.

V10 is highlighted for reference.  About this part of Paul's long sentence, Ellicott observes this:

> (10) **That in the dispensation of the fulness of times**.—The
> connection marked in our version seems certainly erroneous. The words
> should be connected with the previous verse, and translated thus:
> **which He purposed in Himself for administration (or disposal) of the fulness of the (appointed) seasons, to gather, &c**. We note
>
> - (1) that the word “dispensation” is usually applied to the action of the servants of God, as “dispensers of His mysteries.” (See Eph
>   3:2; 1 Cor 9:17; Col 1:25.) Here, however, and in Ephesians 3:10, it
>   is applied to the disposal of all by God Himself, according to “the
>   law which He has set Himself to do all things by.” Next
> - (2) that the word “fulness,” or completeness, frequently used by St. Paul, is only found in connection with time in this passage, and
>   in Galatians 4:4 (“when the fulness of time was come”). There,
>   however, the reference is to a point of time, marking the completion
>   of the preparation for our Lord’s coming; here, apparently, to a
>   series of “seasons,” “which the Father hath put in His own power”
>   (Acts 1:7) for the completion of the acts of the Mediatorial kingdom
>   described in the words following. (Comp Matt 16:3; Luke 21:24; 1 Thess
>   5:1; 1 Tim 2:6; 4:1; 6:15; Titus 1:3.)

Comment: Does the construction of the sentence itself give us any indicators of the use of the art. in determining if the dispensation takes place at the same time of the fullness of the seasons to gather. or if the dispensation of the fullness of seasons to gather are at the same time, the holy and without blame presentation as well as the adoption have scriptures of taking place in the future, as well as our redemption. so could it be that the dispensation is what is now taking place for the redemption of the church, which is for the seasons to gather all. the three remaining trumpets, atonement..

Comment: *or if the dispensation for the fullness of the seasons to gather, being the holy and....

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - the construction of the sentence is long but uncomplicated.  V10 simply means that God planned to bring all things under Christ, and at the fulness of time, that is, according to the prophetic timetable.

Comment: I didnt wright mycomment above correctly, my question is, does the contruction of the greek, allow for: "a dispensation of the fullness," for the appointed seasons. meaning that "fullness" is connected to dispensation?

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - there is no "dispensation" idea in the NT - that is a modern Platonic idea.  The only big change in "dispensation" (to use a non-Biblical word) is when Jesus returns which is what this verse is discussing.